# Is there any better way to detect a user's online status rather than keeping sending AJAX requests to the server by using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there any good way to detect whether a user is online or not?

I have no any other idea but still using an inefficient way to solve this problem: I keep sending AJAX requests to the server at regular intervals by using `setInterval`, and then the server detects whether the user is online or not according to the timestamp of the request.

I know that it is not a good way. And sure, it wasted lots of Internet bandwidth and increased the burden on the server. But it is also the easiest way to realize the function.

So is there anyone who has any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

I myself had the same issue.

2 possible solutions (don't use both)

••1•• jquery IDLE : https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle

••2•• a document.addEventListener ( document.addEventListener )

like this

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() { 
    wistatus = document.visibilityState; 
    if ( wistatus == "visible" ) { /* AJAX STUFF user in HERE */ }  
    else { /* AJAX STUFF use out HERE */ }
});
```